# How can I provide my password to OpenJDK's ktab.exe if my password has a space in it?

Tags: java, keytab

How can I provide my password to OpenJDK's ktab.exe on Windows if my password has a space in it?

- I tried quotation marks around it, but it seems to take the quotation marks as part of the password.
- I tried without quotation marks; I got "Useless extra argument"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to supply it on the command line, but if I just **avoid supplying any password**, ktab.exe will prompt me for the password nicely, which I can then type normally.